# question about convergences for prime related sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory

Let $a_n$ be a nonincreasing sequence of positive numbers.

Show that $\sum \limits_{p \text{ is prime}} a_p$ where $p$ runs over all prime numbers  converges if and only if $\sum \limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\log n}$ converges ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the prime number theorem?

Comment: @Bcpicao sure, this question shows up  in a notes about number theory i am reading

Comment: Nice! Then perhaps I'm reading this wrong, I have to write it up in the morning to check if it works, but as the PNT states that $P( (k \leq n) is prime)$ ~ $\frac{1}{\log{n}}$, taking $a_n=a_p$ if n is prime, $0$ else,  makes the two general terms equivalent for large n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primes have logarithmic density in the natural numbers, this should give us some intuition as to why this is true.

For the proof, we make use of partial summation, which is the analogue of integration by parts for sums:
$$\sum_{n\leqslant N}f(n)\,\Delta g(n) = f(N)g(N+1)-f(1)g(1)-\sum_{n<N}g(n+1)\Delta f(n).$$
Here $\Delta f(n)$ denotes the forward difference $f(n+1)-f(n)$.

For the first sum, take $f(n) = a_n$ and $g(n) = n$. Notice that $\Delta g(n)=1$, and since we're summing over primes, $\sum_{p\leqslant N}g(p) = \sum_{n\leqslant N}\pi(n)$. Thus we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{p\leqslant N}a_p = \sum_pa_p\cdot1 &= a_N\,\pi(N+1) - \sum_{n<N}\pi(n+1)\,(a_{n+1}-a_{n}) \\
&\sim a_N\, \frac{N+1}{\log(N+1)} - \sum_{n<N}\frac{n+1}{\log(n+1)}\,(a_{n+1}-a_{n})  \tag{$*$}
\end{align*}
by the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).

Treating the second sum with the same $f$ and $g$, we get
$$\sum_{2\leqslant n\leqslant N}\frac{a_n}{\log n} = \sum_{2\leqslant n \leqslant N}\frac{a_n}{\log n}\cdot 1 = \frac{a_N}{\log N}\,(N+1)-\sum_{2\leqslant n < N}n\Big(\frac{a_{n+1}}{\log(n+1)}-\frac{a_{n}}{\log n}\Big),$$
which clearly converges if and only if $(*)$ converges.